# findOneAndUpdate fails using MEAN stack

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, mean-stack

Here's my code on my **layout.handlebars**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        var socket = io();

        //     //understand button
        $(".understandbtn").click(function(){
            //reset the timer every 3 second of interval
            $('.actionBtnFloat').css('z-index','0');

            //e_money
             var deduct = 100;
             var newMoney = {{user.e_money}} - deduct;

  // send a message to the server that the e-money value has changed
 //get the current user
             socket.emit('update e-money',getUserName(), newMoney);

             // console.log("Emitting the data to the server side - emoney" + getUserName() + "with the name money of :" + newMoney);
            //end 

            clearTimeout(interval);
            //send the data to the server
            socket.emit('chat message', getUser());
            var interval = setTimeout(function(){
                $('.'+getUser()).fadeIn();
            },5000);
        });

             socket.on('update e-money response', function (data) {
             alert("Your money is: "+ data.newMoney);
             console.log("Your money is:" + data.newMoney);
             });

            socket.on('update e-money error', function (err,data) {
                if(err) throw err;
            // alert("Could not update your money: "+ data.error);
            // console.log("Could not update your money"+ data.error);
                alert("Sucessfully updated  your money");
                console.log("Sucessfully updated your money");
            });
```

And on my server here it is how i update my record but its not working
is it because of the error?

```
//emoney
socket.on('update e-money', function (data) {
var userName = data.username;
var newMoney = data.newMoney;
var query = {username: userName};

// update the entry on the database
User.findOneAndUpdate(query, { e_money: newMoney }, { upsert: true, new: true }, function (err, doc) {
if (err) {
  io.emit('update e-money error', { error: err });
  console.log(err);
} else {
    io.emit('update e-money response', { e_money: newMoney });
    console.log(newMoney);
}
});
});

//end emoney
```

Now it says couldn't update my record
Is it because im not using the _id instead?

here's my error

message: 'Cast to number failed for value "undefined" at path "e_money"',
  name: 'CastError',
  stringValue: '"undefined"',
  kind: 'number',
  value: undefined,
  path: 'e_money',
  reason: undefined }

Comment: What does the `console.log(newMoney | err);` print?

Comment: it doesn't print actually . I don't know why even if it has a console.log

Comment: Did you try to debug and see where it fails? try to move the `console.log` up before the `io.emit`

Comment: i'll edit my question

Comment: I just figure it out and now the problem is it can't update i guess my syntax is inappropriate

Comment: try to change `query` inside the findUpdate to `{"username": userName}`

Comment: @ElmerDantas okay sir let me try .

Comment: @ElmerDantas not working sir

Comment: are you use mongoose, right? try like this `User.findOneAndUpdate({username: userName}, {$set:{e_money: newMoney}}, {upsert: true, new: true}, function(err, user){})` if this doesn't work (like the object is not updated) propably the filter is not correct

Comment: yeah i was guessing that way also . how can i get the id of my mongoose sir cause i tried it something like this
`User.findOneAndUpdate({"_id":xxxxxxxxxx"}, {"$set":{"e_money": "1000"}}, {upset:true, returnOriginal:false}, function(err,doc){
`
and it works

Comment: but it is manual mode obviously

Comment: the user exists?  if exists you have the _id when you retrieve the data to client...you're app structure is not clear though

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147135/discussion-between-theginxx009-and-elmer-dantas).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By doing this achieved what i want

```
User.findOneAndUpdate({"username":userName}, 
{"$set":{"e_money": newMoney }}, { upsert: true, returnOriginal:false }, 
function (err, doc) {
```